# How to compare first character of string to other PHP

Tags: php, string

I have below code

```
$allArray =  array("AAAAA","ABBB","BBBB","BDDFD","TTTT","ZZZZ");
```

What i need when first character of each string is change then i have to make some font changes for that.

```
foreach($allArray as $data){

     $first = substr($data,0,1);

     // HOW TO COMPARE FIRST WITH OTHER VALUES & IF A IS CHANGED FROM B,T or Z THEN I HAVE TO MAKE THAT FIRST CHARACTER COLOR CHANGE & INCREASE THE SIZE OF FONT.

}
```

I need output Like below

AAAAA
ABBBB

BBBB
BDDFD

TTT

ZZZZ

So all alphabates in different group.

First character of that string with different color & different size.

So for

BBBB
BDDFD

here from BBBB -> First B would be in different color & different size

Comment: how it will be changes?? by user or??

Comment: Your question is unclear.

Comment: what do you want? what are you comparing with what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an array key to look behind by using `$your_array[$current_key-1]`:

```
$allArray =  array("AAAAA","ABBB","BBBB","BDDFD","TTTT","ZZZZ");
sort($allArray);
$color = rand_color(); // initial
$break = ' ';

foreach($allArray as $k => $value) {

    if($k == 0) { // initial
        echo "<span style='color: $color; font-size: 35px;'>$value[0]</span>" . substr($value, 1);
        continue;
    }

    if($allArray[$k-1][0] != $value[0]) {
        $color = rand_color(); // generate new row
        $break = '<br/>';
        $value = "<span style='color: $color; font-size: 35px;'>$value[0]</span>" . substr($value, 1);
    } else {
        $break = ' '; // continuation

    }

    echo "$break $value";
}

function rand_color() { // this is just for presentational purposes
    return sprintf('#%06X', mt_rand(0, 0xFFFFFF));
}
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ISUc40)

Another way is to use a hashmap then presenting it after the gathering:

```
$allArray =  array("AAAAA","ABBB","BBBB","BDDFD","TTTT","ZZZZ");

$group = array();
foreach ($allArray as $value) {
    $group[$value[0]][] = $value;
}

foreach($group as $values) {
    $values = implode(' ', $values);
    $color = rand_color();
    $values = "<span style='color: $color; font-size: 35px;'>$values[0]</span>" . substr($values, 1) . '<br/>';
    echo $values;
}

function rand_color() {
    return sprintf('#%06X', mt_rand(0, 0xFFFFFF));
}
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/IZsGa2)

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($allArray as $data => $value){

     $first = substr($value,0,1);
}
```

`$data` only have index of array not the value. value is with `$value` so comparison will go with `$value`.

Comment: Ok. But how to compare??

Comment: `foreach($allArray as $data)` `$data` consists of values

Answer (score -1):

emmm try this

```
foreach($allArray as $data => $value){ 
     $first = substr($value,0,1); 
     $newString = "<span color='red'>$firts</span>".substr($value,1,strlen($value)); 
}
```